# Why don't I see the XAMPP page on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, mysql, php, apache-httpd, xampp

I am trying to install PHP MySQL on Mint 12. I downloaded and installed [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html). According to the tutorial, when I go to `localhost` in a browser I should see this:

[image]

Instead, I see:

```
It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

I realize this is the Apache success page, but why am I seeing it instead of the XAMPP page? How do I fix it? Where should PHP source files be stored on Mint?

Comment: I have php on windows xp so i don't care if i works or not on mint, i just want mysql to work coz i need it a lot

Comment: Someone: Could you tell what solved the issue?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez first you have to uninstall php, mysql and apache.... then go to synaptic package manager and click "complete remove" for any package related to apache mysql and php coz they will never be uninstalled completely from the terminal. u can do `sudo apt-get autoremove`.. and then reinstall xampp and see if it works. u can also follow this http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez I actually didn't install xampp again, i installed only php mysql apache (lamp) if you are going to install xampp you'll be installing php mysql apache proftpd phpmyadmin and i think filezilla server...i don't need those stuff and i use sqlbudddy instead of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer, found by the asker :

1. You have to uninstall php, mysql and apache from the linux distribution
2. Go to synaptic package manager and click "complete remove" for any package related to apache mysql and php
3. You can also issue a `sudo apt-get autoremove`
4. Then reinstall xampp and see if it works.

See this [tutorial](http://howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) for detailed steps